# QGIS: Error when using Undo/Redo on layers loaded from PostgreSQL database

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3, undo-redo

I am working with layers loaded from PostgreSQL(11.7)/PostGIS database to QGIS 3.10.7.

When I try to undo/redo changes made on the layer it fails, sometimes during the undo and basically every time when doing redo (I didn't notice any pattern in it). Apparently, there is some problem with the cursor in the PostgreSQL database, but I don't know why.

```
Fetching from cursor qgis_398 failed Database error: ERROR: cursor "qgis_398" does not exist
```

I thought that QGIS is able to handle in the background all the functionality for undo/redo on database layers (in newer versions at least).

It looks like when the layers are in editing mode, changes (creating new features at least) are happening on the QGIS side and are not propagated to the database. When I do "redo" QGIS is trying to obtain the data from database via cursor, but the cursor was not set beforehand. Perhaps because the changes were not pushed to database.

Over time I tried several versions of PostgreSQL (9, 11, 12) and QGIS (3.10, 3.14), the same problem persisted. After studying logs made by the database server I have found, that the QGIS is saving the state of the layers as a SAVEPOINT in database when I start editing. During the edits, QGIS is creating various cursors (with *ST_AsBinary* function). I am guessing that by doing this, the QGIS gets the actual data from the database. The problem occurs when the QGIS calls for the ROLLBACK (when I do undo in the QGIS). All the changes that was done after declaring the SAVEPOINT are lost, but QGIS then tries to FETCH the CURSOR that is lost due to this. This causes the error and the transaction is aborted.

```
"DECLARE CURSOR",2020-11-24 15:51:20 CET,15/18,126847,LOG,00000,"duration: 0.473 ms  statement: DECLARE qgis_305 BINARY CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT st_asbinary(""geometry"",'NDR'),""id"",""fk_MK"",""popisky_z""::text,""popisky_y""::text,""poznamka""::text,""typ_useku""::text,""umisteni""::text,""provoz""::text,""popisky_x""::text,array_out(""par_cis_ve"")::text,array_out(""par_cis_hl"")::text,""KU""::text,""stav_MK""::text,""cislo_kom""::text,""cislo_us""::text,""povrch""::text,""plocha""::text,""delka""::text,""sirka""::text FROM ""MK"".""usek"" WHERE ""geometry"" && st_makeenvelope(-533970.59677669638767838,-1124501.15351219591684639,-532212.18808578583411872,-1123600.86123963561840355,5514)",,,,,,,,,"QGIS"
"ROLLBACK",2020-11-24 15:51:20 CET,15/18,126847,LOG,00000,"duration: 0.065 ms  statement: ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT ""qgis779d8f397d0d4932aa0a""",,,,,,,,,"QGIS"
"FETCH",2020-11-24 15:51:20 CET,15/18,126847,ERROR,34000,"cursor ""qgis_305"" does not exist",,,,,,"FETCH FORWARD 2000 FROM qgis_305",,,"QGIS"
"CLOSE CURSOR",2020-11-24 15:51:20 CET,15/18,126847,ERROR,25P02,"current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block",,,,,,"CLOSE qgis_305",,,"QGIS"
```

Comment: We use PostgreSQL with PostGIS in QGIS heavily, and do not have any issues like this at all. What kind of changes you do? Any plugins involved?

Comment: Also as far as I am aware, QGIS does not save any changes to the database in editing mode until you hit save or quit editing with save. So do you save changes and then try to undo/redo it?

Comment: @Miro We do not use any plugins. I can understand now that QGIS is keeping all changes on my side. What is puzzling to me is, why the redo failes with the above message. Database should not be involved if the changes are only in QGIS.

Comment: Ok. Does your feature class (table) in PostGIS has unique key defined like gid serial primary key?

Comment: @Miro Table has id column which is defined as unique as well asi primary key. It is not explicitly declared as serial, instead the sequence is defined by it's default value.
`DEFAULT nextval('"MK".usek_id_seq'::regclass)`

Comment: This is the only thing I can think of as problematic. I would try quick test with your table, copy it, remove your current id column and add new one the way I described. Otherwise I am out of ideas.

Comment: @ Miro I have tried several experiments with the settings, including what you suggested. If I define the id as you said, PostgreSQL changes it internally to`DEFAULT nextval('"MK".usek_id_seq'::regclass)` and creates the corresponding sequence.

Comment: I am sorry to hear you still struggle with this, I tried couple of tests editing layers using adding / updating / deleting, and to use heavily undo/redo which I normally do not touch at all. And I am not able to replicate your problem. QGIS is not sending anything to the database while doing undo / redo. New features have primary key value nextval('my_table.my_gid_seq'::regclass) and that is about it. Can be saved or quit editing without saving, all works as expected.

Comment: @Miro After some tests I've come to an impression that when I start editing, QGIS opens the connection to DB and builds a ransaction that is supposed to change data in DB according the changes in QGIS, only when the editing ends, QGIS commits the transaction to DB. Although I may be wrong on this.

Anyway, can you tell me which versions of QGIS, PostgreSQL and PostGIS you are using? Maybe even send me some test project and SQL dump which you are positive is working? In the same way, I can send you my project/dump and you can test it, for errors. Thank you

Comment: We went through many versions both of QGIS and PostgreSQL (with PostGIS), currently I use QGIS 3.10 and 3.14, PostgreSQL 11 and 12, and all works fine. Maybe try to create some dummy layer with vector research tools in QGIS - like random points or polyline/polygon grid, and export with DB manager into Postgres with id and geom column defined when exporting. And try edit that, if it works.

Comment: @Miro I have done several tests with several versions of PostgreSQL and QGIS and the problem persists. I tried even working with just single layer without any other relations. Only change that I noticed is, that the problem occured later (after many edits). I don't see how could I change the configuration of the database or QGIS to prevent this behaviour. If you say, that everything works for you, could you perhaps send me some dummy layer, that you are absolutely sure that works? I could maybe try editing wit my configuration and see if it works or not.

Comment: I am impressed by your persistence. With your update it seems like it might be actual QGIS bug. I rarely use undo/redo functions, mostly just frequently save/discard. This never happened to me. The only errors I got so far is if I insert features including id and forget to update sequence to max id in database, or create feature in one layer and copy to other which keeps nextval value from source table. Do you know how to report bug on qgis github? I will test a bit redo/undo tonight to see if I can replicate this.

Comment: So I tried about 20 undo/redo, creating features and removing them with no error. As you struggle so much with it I strongly suggest to report to it https://github.com/qgis/QGIS as there is better chance someone will understand what is happening.

Comment: @Miro It's not a total deal breaker, but sometimes it makes the work easier when you can undo/redo, especially as I am trying to develop something for users that are used to do it. I didn't really know about the thing you describe, I will check what is happening with the sequence when copying features. Regarding the github, I have already posted the problem there some time ago. So far no relevant reply.